# Was the term 'renaissance' used during said period?

Tags: language, renaissance

Just as the title suggests, was the term for the renaissance years coined and used during those years, or is it a modern word used retrospectively?

Comment: Welcome to History:Stack Exchange. Thank you for your question; please consider revising it to be more in line with our community expectations. Like many other stacks, we expect questions to [provide evidence of prior research](https://interpersonal.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3227/1599). That helps us to understand the question, and avoids our repeating work you've already done. Our [help], and [other stacks](https://interpersonal.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3224/how-do-i-write-a-good-question) provide additional resources to assist with revisions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sort of.  The Italian artist and critic Giorgio Vasari (1511–1574), who wrote *The Lives of the Artists*, used the term "[rinascita](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Renaissance#Conception)", which has similar connotations.  However, the term "Renaissance" proper was a later invention according to the book "The Renaissance" written by Paul Johnson.

> The term "Renaissance" was first prominently used by the French
>   historian Jules Michelet in 1858, and it was set in bronze two years
>   later by Jacob Burckhardt when he published his great book The
>   Civilization of the Renaissance in Italy. The usage stuck because it
>   turned out to be a convenient way of describing the period of
>   transition between the medieval epoch, when Europe was "Christendom,"
>   and the beginning of the modern age.

[[Source: New York Times article on The Renaissance](https://www.nytimes.com/books/first/j/johnson-renaissance.html)]